# Open a picture (jpg.) in F#

Tags: f#

I would like to open several pictures (.jpg) with F#.
All my pictures are stored in afile (filepath). I would like to show them to the user.
How can I do this using F#?

To open one picture, it tried something like :

```
open System.IO
let editPicture filepath = 
    let  fileStream = File.Open(filepath,FileMode.Open)
    fileStream.Visible <- True
```

but it doesn t work.

Comment: does "make it visible" mean "show"? If yes show where - your app, some build in App-Viewer, Browser?

Comment: yes visible means show. sorry i don t understand your last sentence " If yes show where - your app, some build in App-Viewer, Browser?"

Comment: the question is easy: you want to open a file (.jpg) and you want to show it to the user. I guess in your application? What kind of application? You "normal" F# app will be a console application. There are no templates for WinForms or WPF out of the box so I just don't know in which way you want to show the picture to your user from the dos-box.

Comment: I guess you really don't know where to start. F# is not the best choice for UIs if you are a .net beginner. Try using C#/VB.net and WinForms to load and show some pictures fist and then try doing the same in F# (look into the InitializeComponent method that the WinForms desinger generates for you) - you just have to copy.

Comment: Sorry my question was not well formulated. I want to show the pictures on my computer which uses Windows Live. Basically I used F# to rank some pictures based on few characteristics (like colors) and now, I want to show the first five pictures on my computer screen (not to users). Even more basically I want to show on my computer screen 5 pictures (jpg format) from F#.

Comment: so it is a console application? in this case you could use Process.Start to start some external viewer or just copy the pictures you found into a output-directory or even more simple just print the names of the files. For everything else you should consider using WinForms or WPF or some other GUI-Framework

Comment: Thank you thanks to your advice I use PictureBox which seems to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a minimal quick and dirty WinForms F# snippet that shows a .jpg image on a screen:

```
open System
open System.Windows.Forms
open System.Drawing

let form = new Form()
let pb = new PictureBox()
pb.Image <- Image.FromFile(path-to-file-with-your-jpg-image)
pb.SizeMode <- PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize
form.Controls.Add(pb)

[<STAThread>]
do
    Application.Run(form)
```

This may give you some initial traction and feel on what is involved into reaching your goal. But overall I agree with Carsten König that learning curve for doing UIs with F# is quite steep.